# Check values between two arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Feel like the title summed it up pretty well. I have two large arrays, all containing ids.

One is the old_list and one is the current_list. What I would like to do is this:

- delete all the values in the old_list, that are not present in the current_list
- if the value in the current_list is present in the old_list don't do anything
- if the value in current_list is new then create it and add it to the old_list

This is set as a background job that updates every 4 hours. Thus I want to see if any new value have appeared, or been removed since I last checked.

Here is what I have currently, which is not complete:

```
    twitter.follower_ids("#{uid}").each do |f_id|
      # unless user already has follower id saved
      unless followers.map(&:follower_id).include?(f_id.to_s)
        followers.create do |follower|
          follower.follower_id = f_id
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the below Set operation :

```
(old_list & current_list) | current_list
```

Example :

```
old_v = [1,2,43]
new_v = [1,11,21]
(old_v & new_v) | new_v # => [1, 11, 21]
```

[`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) and [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C).

Comment: could you go into some more detail not sure if I understand this?

Comment: Nice. Wasn't aware of this, how would I go about implementing this into my example though where I have some saving etc?

Comment: @sja Just call `#each` method like `((old_list & current_list) | current_list).each { |item| your code here }`

Comment: but then I'd also have to delete the old_list every time and replace it with the new one right?

Comment: @sja do this `old | new) - new`, it will give you items which is to be deleted from the `old_list`... and then delete it using the resultant id